# Firestore: Adding a value into a collection and another value into that new collection's field

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How would I go about adding 'text' as a collection to the 'radioMedia' (TV Show/Movie) doc, and then 'radioAmount' as a field to the 'text' collection?

```
    var radioAmount;
    if(document.getElementById('smallPromo').checked) {
        radioAmount = 500;
    } else if (document.getElementById('largePromo').checked) {
        radioAmount = 1000;
    }

    var radioMedia;
    if(document.getElementById('show').checked) {
        radioMedia = "TV Shows";
    }
    else if (document.getElementById('movie').checked) {
        radioMedia = "Movies";
    }

    var text = document.getElementById('textSearch').value;

    firebase.firestore().collection('Promoted Media').doc(radioMedia).set({

        amount: radioAmount,
        name: text

    });
```

What I have here just adds 'radioAmount' and 'text' as fields to the radioMedia doc

Answer (score 0):

You add a `document` to a collection. The `document` can be defined as a plain object, e.g.:

```
var myObj = {};
myObj.name = "John";
myObj.age = 21;
```

then `firebase.firestore.collection("people").doc().set(myObj);`

You can also add a [sub-collection](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model#subcollections) to a document.

Comment: No that's not quite what I was looking for; what I currently have basically does the same exact thing you're showing me. What I want to do is create a collection in a document, and then add fields to that new collection. What we have now just adds fields to a document.

Comment: You can also add a [sub-collection](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model#subcollections) to a document.